# biblatex: format of author field in op.cit. loc.cit

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` and I must strictly obey some formatting rules for my thesis. Here's the problem: `biblatex` does not display author's first name (initial or full, whatever) when calling op.cit. and loc.cit. formatting.

I've been digging into forums and `biblatex` source files (`.bst`, `.def`, `.cbx` and so on ...) and I can't solve the problem despite hours of search. Please help me, I'm getting crazy!

By the way, how could I disambiguate Jane Doe from Joan Doe if using `firstinits=true` in such case?

Many thanks for your help!

MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,backend=biber,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{SmithJ,
    Author = {John Smith},
    Title = {A great paper for sure},
    Year = {2000}}
@article{DoeJane,
    Author = {Jane Doe},
    Title = {An even better paper},
    Year = {2002}}
@article{DoeJoan,
    Author = {Joan Doe},
    Title = {This one is published},
    Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Smith dummy ref\footcite{SmithJ}.
DoeJane dummy ref\footcite{DoeJane}.
Call opcit with Smith ref\footcite[39]{SmithJ}.
Call opcit with DoeJane ref\footcite[35]{DoeJane}.
Introduce DoeJoan ref\footcite[18]{DoeJoan}.
Call loccit with DoeJane ref\footcite[35]{DoeJane}.
Call loccit with SmithJ ref\footcite[39]{SmithJ}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I have changed your MWE slightly to use `\addbibresource{<file>.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{<file>}`, as the latter is deprecated in favour of the former.

Comment: What about `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}`? This will always give you "Last, First" names.

Comment: `firstinits=true` seems to interfere with `uniquename` trackers, though, so always using initials except when needed seems quite hard. In fact, if you use `firstinits=true` and `uniquename=full`, you will receive a warning: `'firstinits' conflicts with 'uniquename=full' Setting 'uniquename=init'`. You could override that with `\AtEndPreamble{\setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{uniquename=full}}`, but I did not like the result of that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot moewe for your help!

`\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{last-first}` does the trick perfectly.